# Git log: log of future revisions

Tags: git

When I check out a previous commit of a git repository, 'git log' no longer shows commits that were committed after the currently checked out commit.

So, the question is: how do get a log of commits after the currently checked out one?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I *highly* suggest using `gitk --all` to visualize multiple branches and history.

Comment: Also not an answer, but I suggest using: tig --all

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `--all` flag to see all revisions, as in

```
git log --all
```

If you are just interested in the future revisions, you can also use

```
git log ..@{1}      # assuming you just switched from the future master
git log ..abcdef    # assuming abcdef is the newest future commit
```

Comment: can you explain the `..@{1}`?

Comment: @drzaus `@{n}` is the n-th commit in your current branch, so `@{1}` is simply the newest commit in the current branch. The double-dot `..` indicates show everything reachable from the commit to the right that is not reachable from the commit to the left. Therefore, `HEAD..@{1}` shows everything that is reachable from the newest commit in the current branch but not the current commit (and `HEAD` can be left out).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is: you don't know the children commits, only the parent comments.
And if you checkout directly a commit SHA1, you are in [Detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) (ie not on any branch).

One potential solution would be to list all the branches which contains your commit: "[How to know which branch a “git log” commit belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132381/6309)".
And then do a git log for each of those branches.