# Get commits per branch in git "update" hook

Tags: git, hook, githooks

Consider next pseudo-code thats create a required git log:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b 123-test-branch-1
git commit -m "#123 b1 c1"
git commit -m "#123 b1 c2"
git push
git checkout master
git checkout -b 456-test-branch-2
git commit -m "#456 b2 c1"
git commit -m "#456 b2 c2"
git push
git checkout 123-test-branch-1
git merge 456-test-branch-2
git commit -m "#123 b1 c3"
git push
```

In a real-world my `update` hook in remote git repository validates branch name and commit message formats. Branch name and commit message must contain issue number, for example, in `123-test-branch-1` and `#123 b1 c1` the issue number is `123`. When branch is pushed, hook extract issue number from branch and commit message and compare it. If they are not equal, hook exits with error.

This works great, when I push branch that has only "own" commits. But, git log example above, pushed branch `123-test-branch-1` has commits from merged branch `456-test-branch-2` so hook try to compare all commits from both branches only with pushed branch `123-test-branch-1` and exits with error because commits from `456-test-branch-2` has issue number `456`, when `123` is expected.

To receive commits, I use `git log --pretty=%s ${oldRef}..${newRef}`, where `oldRef` and `newRef` is "update" hook arguments.

So, my question is how to solve this problem. Somehow group commits per branch, or filter commits from branch that pushed now (but if `456-test-branch-2` is local branch and never pushed and never validated, hook may skip invalid commits), or something else.

Comment: Maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131735/575643

Comment: I guess this is even more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/575643

Comment: You should also consider the case where, instead of three separate `git push` commands, the user waits and does one `git push origin 123-test-branch-1 456-test-branch-2` at the end.

Comment: @torek, in this case, ``update`` hook will be run twice, for each pushed branch, and for ``123-test-branch-1`` git log will be the same as with three ``git push`` commands, right? If so, the problem is same: commits, merged from ``456-test-branch-2`` will be processed.

Comment: Correct, the update hook runs once per update. That's why I suggest, at least for merge traversals, using `--first-parent`. You might also want to restrict precisely *who* can do merges and/or when. For something quite fancy (though still flawed), see my sample pre-receive hook [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update hook does not get enough information: it cannot get a "global view" of the incoming hash IDs.  A pre- or post-receive hook does,<sup>1</sup> and therefore does get enough information—at least for some purposes.

The biggest problem lies with new branch creation.  Suppose, for instance, an update is delivering the names `refs/heads/a` and `refs/heads/b`, where both names are new (their old hashes are the null hash), and `refs/heads/a` points to commit `N2` and `refs/heads/b` points to commit `N3` in this graph fragment:

```
                 N2   <-- A
                /
...--O--O--O--N1
                \
                 N3   <-- B
```

where all the `O` commits are "old" (as in, were reachable from existing branch or tag names before) and the `N` commits are "new", as in were never reachable before, and are therefore listed by:

```
git rev-list refs/heads/a refs/heads/b --not \
    $(git for-each-ref --format '%(refname) |
        egrep -v '^(refs/heads/a|refs/heads/b)$')
```

It's clear that these three `N` commits are "new", but to which branch should you assign `N1`?

There is no single right answer to this.  Commit `N1` is on both branches, after all.

In any case, if you are more concerned with merge commits—as in, e.g.:

```
...O1--O2--N1--N2   <-- A
              /
...-O3--O4--N3    <-- B
```

—you may want to use `--first-parent` traversals.  Here we can believe, based on these two branch-name updates (`A` moves from `O2` to `N2`, `B` moves from `O4` to `N3`)—that the first parent of `N2` is `N1` (it's possible, but difficult, to make this happen the other way around), so following `--first-parent`s will "assign" commit `N1` to `A` and not to `B`.  Again, if you are doing this from an update hook, rather than a pre- or post-receive hook, that may be the best you can do, since you do not get the information that *both* `A` *and* `B` are proposed to be updated.

---

<sup>1</sup>A post-receive hook is run after dropping all the locks, so it races against other operations that may update reference names.  A pre-receive hook gets all the proposed updates and therefore there is a big lock around reference name updates, so it's clearly safer, in some sense, to do this work there.

The drawback is that the pre-receive hook runs while holding a big lock, so anything "slow" it does, prohibits parallelism.

Comment: What you can say about ``git reflog show --all | grep <hash>``? This command can show branch in which commit was first appeared. This approach has limitation: only last 90 days available due to git gc by default, but for most cases, this is acceptable solution. So, I can find branches for all commits, intercepted by hook (``update`` or ``pre-receive``), and run validation for each branch.

Comment: The reflog technique has three flaws: (1) it only works for 90 days or other reflog expiration, as you note; (2) It only works if reflogs are *enabled* (they are optional); and (3) most important for a hook, it only works *on the machine on which the branch is created*, which is not the server receiving the push (on server bare repositories reflogs are disabled by default as well).

Comment: After few experiments with ``git reflog`` on remote repo I can state that reflog-based solution is not working. Can you explain more detail, how I can find branches using your approach with ``git rev-list``? I need to find branches for all received (in hook) commits and know which commit from which branch for proper validation.

Comment: The fact is that you *cannot* solve this in general; the best you can do is handle specific cases that you decide are then "good enough". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/1256452 for more.

Comment: Can we also abreviate with:
`git rev-list refs/heads/a refs/heads/b --not --exclude="refs/heads/a" --exclude="refs/heads/b" --all`
Anybod know if that works? according to the doc it should ...

Comment: @Gabriel: I think that probably works, but I think `--exclude` isn't in some very old versions of Git.